# Rule Based Line Symbology causing weird behaviour changes on zoom

Tags: qgis, symbology, line, rendering, rule-based

I'm fairly sure this is an actual bug and have raised a ticket in Github, but it hasn't been looked at yet and just would to see if anyone else has any other ideas that I can try, or can see anything I'm doing wrong. It was working fine then just started misbehaving.

Fairly straight forward in principle... just a line layer with gradient on an attribute. I've converted that gradient to rules and added other nested rules, all based on attributes.

This is how it looks (and used to at any scale) at 1:2302 (with all the symbology rules working)

[image]

However when I zoom out to 1:4000 and beyond it looks like this (with the symbology jumped to the else clause)

[image]

The rule appears to have jumped from the if (thicker lines with graduated colour) to the else (thin lines fixed colour) on zoom.... The attribute is just a text field so shouldn't change. It didn't used to do this and then it suddenly started, initially it was a bit quirky in that I could zoom out far enough and it would start working again and it seems to have degenerated to the point where it only displays properly if I've very zoomed it.

Full Rules here:

[image]

Additionally I have tried to:

- Copy the layer delete the rules and start again, no luck.
- Reimported the layer and saved as a separate file, still the same.
- Restarted QGIS and PC a couple of times.
- Upgraded to latest QGIS (3.34.3-Prizren) still the same.
- Created new user profile.

Comment: Please provide example data and the style.

Comment: It's private data, so I can't just share... I am trying to set up a test set that can show it...  I came close to replicating it and had other issues appear that seemed to be related to 'Render layers as Group' - by toggling that I was able to reset some issues... I'll post with an update when I'm able to...